# Bypassing tumblr terms page

Tags: .net, vb.net

Everytime i load a tumblr page with requests it automaticly redir to a eu agreement thing from tumblr, any way to bypass this without having to login in?

[redir page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlSFm.png)

[website link](https://www.tumblr.com/privacy/consent?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fthemesbyeris.tumblr.com%2Ftutorial01)

Comment: Does this only happen if you are accessing the internet from Europe? I don't have this problem in North America.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a better answer yet, but this may do for now, depending on your situation. Try to go to tumblr in incognito mode. Click "Get Started." When the page pops up, accept it, and press F12 (on chrome at least). Go to `Application` tab, then `Cookies`, then `https://www.tumblr.com`, you'll see a cookie `pfg`. Copy the value of that cookie, and then when accessing tumblr from your application, [set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78c837bd.aspx) the `pfg` cookie to that value before pressing get started.

Warning, this is probably a fine workaround for an application for use only by you and trusted others. However, I cannot guarantee that the information in that cookie doesn't have a session id or something similar that you would NOT want untrusted individuals to have.